# How well are the real parts of Zeta function zeros bounded?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I know that it has been proven that $\mathrm{Re}(\rho)<1$, and RH is $\mathrm{Re}(\rho)=1/2$, where $\rho$ is zero of Riemann zeta function.
Can someone summarize, or link me to very recent improvement on this "Real part of zero"?

Specifically, I have few questions related to this.

> 1. Is real part of zero of zeta function always rational?
> 2. What is best bound for the real part? That is, what is the smallest $\delta$ discovered, that for all zero of zeta function, following
>      always holds. $$|\mathrm{Re}(\rho)-1/2|<\delta $$

Answer (score 1):

1. That's not known.
2. The best known bound for the non-trivial zeros is $\delta=\dfrac12$.